# VBA Code to Find a specific cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of data starting in C11 and goes down to C800. I want to click a button and for it to look through this data and find the value in C5. Then in column A adjacent to the value. I would like to put the value in C4. Please let me know if this is possible. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Add a new module and paste this in (replacing `sheet1` with whatever sheet you are doing this for):

```
Sub Button_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheet1.Range("C11:C800").Find(Sheet1.Range("C5")).Offset(,-2).Value = Sheet1.Range("C4").Value
End Sub
```

Add a new button to your sheet and point it to your Button_Click() macro.

Comment: you're too nice.

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm in a terrible mood today too, but this was only a single line of code so it's a freebie! (Plus it was fun to think through this as a one-liner) - UPDATED: Two liner to avoid errors

Comment: @OP, remove that "On Error Resume Next" if this doesn't seem to be working. Once you you fix it up based on the error messages, then stick that line back in to keep it quiet again.

Comment: @JNevill won't this only find the first instance of the value in C5 in the range?

Comment: thanks guys for the help!